# Use Ubuntu server as VPN PRovider

Tags: server, vpn, routing

I recently came up with the following project.

My home network consist of:

- an ISP modem/router
- a second router used as an access point/switch
- an Ubuntu server used as file server - cloud server - media center, etc
- various devices connected using both ethernet and wifi on either of those routers.
- My work pc

The goal is to make my Work pc connect to the internet through my paid VPN Serivce app running on my Ubuntu server, without having to physically connect my work pc to my server and without my server having to have two NICs, but just using my normal routers connectivity as i already have it now.

In other words what i need to do is to have my Work pc connected to my VPN provider without having to touch anything software-wise on it. Something like having it connected to a vpn enabled router, only without having one and without having all the other devices connected to the vpn.

Where should i start???? :D

Comment: It's not really clear what you are asking. If your goal is to connect your work PC to a commercial VPN provider, what does your file server on your home network have to do with anything?  Also, does your employer and the owner of the work PC know that you're trying to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. This question answer site is not the best place to flesh out your new project ideas. It works best if you have a specific question or a problem. See the [site help](https://askubuntu.com/help) for how to ask questions here.